# How to join the values in-between two values in a list

Tags: flutter, list, dart, integer

I have this list `[null, 3, 5, null]` and I want to join the values in-between `null`s and put it into the same list
For example:

> [null, 3, 5, null] into [null, 35, null]

I made this one extension that groups all the values between two `null`s

```
extension GroupByNull<T> on List<T> {
  List<List<T>> groupByNull() {
    final groupedList = <List<T>>[];
    var list = this;

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (list[i] == null) {
        if (i > 0) {
          groupedList.add(list.sublist(0, i));
        }
        list = list.sublist(i + 1);
        i = 0;
      }
    }

    if (list.isNotEmpty) {
      groupedList.add(list);
    }

    return groupedList;
  }
}
```

Which returns `[[3, 5]]` for `[null, 3, 5, null]`... But I want it to be joined together and added to the original list in the same index

How can I solve this...
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you can't operate on an arbitrary `List<T>` because there's no general way to combine two elements of some arbitrary type `T`.  What you want could make sense for `List<int?>` or maybe `List<String?>`. (Or maybe it could work on an arbitrary `List<T>` *input* if you want a `List<String?>` output.)

Assuming that you want to operate on `List<int?>`, then basically as you iterate over your input list, keep track of your current accumulated value.  If you encounter `null`, add the current value (if any) to your output `List` along with the `null`.  Don't forget to add the current accumulated value (if any) when you're done iterating in case there isn't a final `null` element.

```dart
extension GroupByNull on List<int?> {
  List<int?> groupByNull() {
    var result = <int?>[];
    int? currentValue;
    for (var element in this) {
      if (element != null) {
        currentValue = (currentValue ?? 0) * 10 + element;
      } else {
        if (currentValue != null) {
          result.add(currentValue);
          currentValue = null;
        }
        result.add(currentValue);
      }
    }

    if (currentValue != null) {
      result.add(currentValue);
    }
    return result;
  }
}

void main() {
  print([null, 3, 5, null].groupByNull()); // Prints: [null, 35, null]

  print([3, 5, null].groupByNull()); // Prints: [35, null]
  print([3, 5, null, null].groupByNull()); // Prints: [35, null, null]
  print([null, 3, 5].groupByNull()); // Prints: [null, 35]
  print([null, null, 3, 5].groupByNull()); // Prints: [null, null, 35]
  print([null, 0, 0, 0, null].groupByNull()); // Prints: [null, 0, null]
  print([null, 1, 2, null, 3, 4, null]
      .groupByNull()); // Prints: [null, 12, null, 34, null]
  print([null].groupByNull()); // Prints: [null]
  print([null, null].groupByNull()); // Prints: [null, null]}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution.

```
extension GroupByNull<T> on List<T> {
  List groupByNull() {
    final groupedList = [];
    var list = this;
    
    list.removeWhere( (value) => value == null); // remove all null values 

    groupedList.add(int.parse(list.join(""))); // combine number left in list
    
    groupedList.insert(0,null); // add null
    groupedList.add(null);
    
    return groupedList;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It works but if you put more characters in the list it'll be added to the same position even if its next to another `null` 
For an example `[null, 3, 5, null, 8, null]` will return `[null, 358, null]` 
I want it to be `[null, 35, null, 8]`